How to read JSON with nested escaped JSON values with OPENJSON
Tackle Table:



TackleID
TackleName




5e8ef3ed-d02a-4582-85d3-4a993521ed0f
Name1


f08c1041-e5b8-4f25-b69b-90d6a59d937e
Name2


8a9317fe-e036-46b4-a1c2-36b5ba0191dc
Name3



TackleResult Table:



TackleResultID
TackleID
RDI




91f50120-dd46-4f10-900d-42e2338dd649
5e8ef3ed-d02a-4582-85d3-4a993521ed0f
[{"Name":"SeIds","Value":"Data"},{"Name":"ISD","Value":"{\"SID\":{\"column\":{\"City\":\"Himachal\",\"Depth\":\"5mts\"}},\"Canded\":false}"}]


949fc210-7349-4dcf-9a64-08c1259cb3c6
f08c1041-e5b8-4f25-b69b-90d6a59d937e
[{"Name":"SeIds","Value":"Data"},{"Name":"ISD","Value":"{\"SID\":{\"column\":{\"City\":\"Delhi\",\"Depth\":\"15mts\"}},\"Canded\":false}"}]


a2162652-27cf-49ea-ba16-b4a396b04030
8a9317fe-e036-46b4-a1c2-36b5ba0191dc
[{"Name":"SeIds","Value":"Data"},{"Name":"ISD","Value":"{\"SID\":{\"column\":{\"City\":\"Agra\",\"Depth\":\"15mts\"}},\"Canded\":false}"}]



Main Table:



MainID
TackleID




45e0fa71-5091-4523-87f1-4f04bdd98cd7
5e8ef3ed-d02a-4582-85d3-4a993521ed0f



Based on the flag @showDelhi = 1 I need to show the all the records with City = Delhi,Himachal and Agra and @showDelhi=0
I need to display records with City=Himachal and Agra,.....but not with City=Delhi
I have written query like below:
Declare @MainId uniqueidentifier='45e0fa71-5091-4523-87f1-4f04bdd98cd7'
Declare @showDelhi  bit = 0;

SELECT  TG.TackleID
FROM Main P
INNER JOIN Tackle TG   ON TG.TackleID = P.TackleID
INNER JOIN TackleResult TRD on TRD.TackleID = TG.TackleID
WHERE P.MainId = @MainId 
AND (1 = @showDelhi OR ((SELECT City FROM OPENJSON((SELECT VALUE FROM OPENJSON (CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),TRD.RDI))with( Name nvarchar(100), Value nvarchar(max)) where Name='ISD')
    ) WITH (City NVARCHAR(100) '$.SID.column.City')) not like '%Himachal%'))


Above query is working fine when @showDelhi  = 1 but When @showDelhi = 0, it is throwing below error:

JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 't' is found at position 2.

Didn't get what was the issue.
If querying using 1=1 and 1=0 was not a good practice, please suggest me alternate ways.

The error complains about the JSON string, not the catch-all 1=@show. This condition will result in bad performance but doesn't affect how JSON is parsed

Your JSON isn't valid. "Value":"{"SID":{" isn't valid syntax for JSON (You effective have {"JsonArray":"{"UnquotedNode":"UnquotedValue"}"}. Surely the object should not be in double quotes?

My json was
[{"Name":"SeIds","Value":"Data"},{"Name":"ISD","Value":"{"SID":{"column":{"City":"Delhi","Depth":"15mts"}},"Canded":false}"}]
some how slashes are not coming in the question, please check once

Edit your question instead of posting the comments

I stand by my statement: Surely the object should not be in double quotes. Why "{\"SID\":{\"column\":{\...? Why not just "Value":{"SID":{"Column":...?

Front end team will serialize the string and We will insert as is into Database. We are following that pattern

When you start needing to break open json data to get individual elements for WHERE or ON predicates like this is the time to start evaluating what you need to do to store those elements in their own columns in the schema, so you only parse the json at INSERT/UPDATE time. Without exaggeration, performance will improve by multiple orders of magnitude.

"Front end team will serialize the string"  Then get your front end team to stop inserting such bad JSON.

@SAREKAAVINASH it doesn't matter who produces this semi-JSON string. It's not JSON and no JSON parser can read it. Any hacks you use to read this will result in data loss a lot sooner than you assume. Fix the bug instead of trying to cover it up

@SAREKAAVINASH on the other hand, if you intend to query the contents you need a separate table or at least separate columns and this is a database design problem, not a JSON problem at all. You can't index JSON text which means your query has to scan all rows. If you had a proper JSON string you could use a indexed computed column that extracts the value you want

If you have a valid JSON content in your table ('[{"Name":"SeIds","Value":"Data"},{"Name":"ISD","Value":{"SID":{"column":{"City":"Himachal","Depth":"15mts"}},"Canded":false}}]) and using the tables from the question, a possible approach is the following statement:
DECLARE @MainId uniqueidentifier = '45e0fa71-5091-4523-87f1-4f04bdd98cd7';
DECLARE @showDelhi bit = 1;

SELECT TG.TackleID
FROM Main P
INNER JOIN Tackle TG ON TG.TackleID = P.TackleID
INNER JOIN TackleResult TRD on TRD.TackleID = TG.TackleID
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT City
   FROM OPENJSON(TRD.RDI) WITH (
      Name nvarchar(100) '$.Name',
      City nvarchar(100) '$.Value.SID.column.City'
   )
   WHERE (Name = N'ISD')  
) J 
WHERE 
   (P.MainId = @MainId) AND
   ((@showDelhi = 1) OR (@showDelhi = 0 AND J.City <> N'Delhi'))

Based on the requirements, you may use a different WHERE clause:
...
WHERE 
   (P.MainId = @MainId) AND
   (
      (@showDelhi = 1 AND J.City IN (N'Delhi', N'Himachal', N'Agra')) OR 
      (@showDelhi = 0 AND J.City <> N'Delhi')
   )


In Tackle Table and TackleResult table I am having  many records with different City, It would be difficult to use OR conditions like this (@showDelhi = 1 AND J.City = 'Delhi') OR (@showDelhi = 0 AND J.City = 'Himachal')

@SAREKAAVINASH, please, edit the question and explain all your requirements.

If @showDelhi = 1, I need to show all Cities data like Delhi,Himachal,Agra
Not only City= Delhi (@showDelhi = 1 AND J.City = N'Delhi')

@SAREKAAVINASH, all you need is the correct WHERE clause. If I understand you correctly, when @showDelhi is 1 you want to show the records with all possible cities. The answer is updated, but the important part in the answer is how the JSON is parsed.
